# awk/sed in script file

Tags: sed, awk

I have input file in this format
time1 = 0.000000
time1 = 0.010000
time1 = 0.020000
time1 = 0.170000

I need to write a script to extract the values and compute the average. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6):

If it follows that exact format through the entire file, you can use this formula

```
awk '{sum += $3} END {print sum/NR}' file
```

If there are other entries in the file that will throw you off... you might need to filter and track the number of matches...

```
awk '/time/ {sum+=$3; total+=1} END {print sum/total}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't knew that $3 would refer to 3rd column of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `awk`, not `sed`. To get you started: this command line will print the numbers only:

```
awk '{print $3}' FILENAME
```

The `expr` command would be a handy way to add the numbers up.